# Draw Points / Lines using MITK

Tags: c++, render, vtk, mitk

I need some help with MITK. I am trying to draw points and lines (actually my goal is display a virtual colonoscopy centerline), under MITK. I created a vtkPolyData which contains the data of the centerline. This is wrapped into a mitk::Surface structure in order to add in a mitk::StandaloneDataStorage:

```
mitk::StandaloneDataStorage::Pointer ds = mitk::StandaloneDataStorage::New();
mitk::DataNode::Pointer dn = mitk::DataNode::New();
mitk::Surface::Pointer aSurface = mitk::Surface::New();
aSurface->Initialize();
aSurface->SetVtkPolyData(polydata); //polydata is a vtkPolyData which contains data
dn->SetData(aSurface);
ds->Add(dn);
renderWindow.GetRenderer()->SetDataStorage(ds); //renderWindow is a QmitkRenderWindow
```

Now, nothing is shown. I assume that something is missing (e.g. indicate the type of rendering).
The camera and its orientation are placed correctly due that I am drawing something else in the same location.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved! 
The trick is put the function *mitk::RenderingManager::GetInstance()->RequestUpdateAll();* every time that you want to render something :-) or when an event/callback is invoked